# Adding images to mySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a set of images I need to add to my database and display them on a webpage using PHP. Ideally, they would show up as thumbnails in their columns and can be enlarged when clicked on. I read about BLOBS but it seems that they are not an optimal solution. I also read that the other way is to reference your images in the columns somehow, but I have no idea how to begin with that. Any help to point me in the right direction would be appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: While you *can* store the images as binary data in a `BLOB` column, the way I suggest is to store the file in your filesystem somewhere and save the *path* to the file in your database (in a `VARCHAR` field).  Such as `'/images/image.png'`.

Comment: You need to upload all images and then save path to each of them in database.

Comment: So just storing the path in a varchar field will display the image? Do I store it with apostrophes so it can recognize it as a path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I won't actually recommend adding images into database. Instead, you may get the image name (like "images/sample.jpg") and store that string into a table in your database. You may then display it using the `<img>` tag in html.

Storing and retrieving images from a database consumes a lot of time, increases the size of the database, and is less efficient.